# userInteractionEnabled not propagated to subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom `ContainerView : UIView` that contains a `UIButton`.
I toggle the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the `ContainerView` on and off in response to various events. Sometimes, the `tappedButton:` method is fired when the container view's `userInteractionEnabled` is NO. How is this possible?

```
@implementation ContainerView
-(void)addButton {
    self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"XX" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:button];
}

-(void)tappedButton:(id)sender {
    // Assertion sometimes fails! 
    // Especially when tapping multiple times very quickly
    assert(self.userInteractionEnabled); 
    // ... do other stuff...
}
// ...
@end
```

I can work around this problem by adding the following method to ContainerView:

```
// With this method, the assertion in the above code sample never fails
-(void)setUserInteractionEnabled:(BOOL)userInteractionEnabled {
    self.button.userInteractionEnabled = userInteractionEnabled;
    [super setUserInteractionEnabled:userInteractionEnabled];
}
```

Why does this fix the problem? My understanding was that setting `userInteractionEnabled=NO` prevents subviews from receiving touches.

Comment: Apple documentation says : When set to NO, user events—such as touch and keyboard—intended for the view are ignored and removed from the event queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the enabled property of button with your current code

```
 [button1 setEnabled:YES];
 button1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```